# Very simple Client/Server Message networking in C# (.NET and Xamarin/Mono)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, mono, network-programming

I would like to write a simple application to send text messages between a server (Windows) and a client (a Xamarin App running on android), which would remotely control music (played by the server) with basic text commands (like "pause", "skip", "play " ...).

The setup I had tought about would work like this:
When I start the android app, it tries to connect to the server (they are in the same local network using LAN/WiFi, so I'd just use my local IP for that). Then, with the connection established, both would be able to send messages to the other one (client -> server: play this song etc, server -> client: song finished, song not found, etc). Of course, that should be done in a threaded or asynchronous manner so that both applications do not block up their UI. The server would run in the background and wait for the next message, which would trigger an event taking care of doing the requested action.

I already searched on how to do this in a beginner friendly way, but haven't found much that I could work with. I only have basic knowledge on asynchronous/threaded programming, and not enough on networking (in .net). Each solution I found wasn't made for a connection to stay open but rather "read stream, send answer, close connection" (which is not what I want) or was far to complex.

I know that there are countless tutorials available, but I simply couldn't make up how to use them for my scenario. Example Code or easy to understand explanations on how to accomplish things like keeping the connection open in a non-blocking way, and how to send and receive a complete, self-contained message, because I can't quite wrap my head around that (if I just read a fixed size of bytes, how can I be sure to get exactly one message ?).

So, I'd be grateful for every tip showing me in the right direction, like for example which of the many classes would be best to use for this (there seems to be an awful lot of them, without notion which is suited for what). I apologize if this question seems rather dumb, but I'm an absolute beginner in this. Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself, after some more research. System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient is working like a charm, and, more importantly, available and working on both platforms I want to target, so I will just go with it.